# MongoDB find lowest missing value

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection in MongoDB that looks something like:

```
{
 "foo": "something",
 "tag": 0,
},
{
 "foo": "bar",
 "tag": 1,
},
{
 "foo": "hello",
 "tag": 0,
},
{
 "foo": "world",
 "tag": 3,
}
```

If we consider this example, there are entries in the collection with `tag` of value `0`, `1` or `3` and these aren't unique values, `tag` value can be repeated. My goal is to find that `2` is missing. Is there a way to do this with a query?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Query1

- in the upcoming mongodb 5.2 we will have sort on arrays that could do this query easier without set operation but this will be ok also
- group and find the min,max and all the values
- take the `range(max-min)`
- the missing are  `(setDifference range_above tags)`
- and from them you take only the smallest => 2

[Test code here](https://cmql.org/play/?q=70598988-m)

```js
aggregate(
[{"$group":
  {"_id":null,
   "min":{"$min":"$tag"},
   "max":{"$max":"$tag"},
   "tags":{"$addToSet":"$tag"}}},
 {"$project":
  {"_id":0,
   "missing":
   {"$min":
    {"$setDifference":
     [{"$range":[0, {"$subtract":["$max", "$min"]}]}, "$tags"]}}}}])
```

Query2

- in Mongodb 5 (the current version) we can use also $setWindowFields
- sort by tag, add the dense-rank(same values=same rank), and the min
- then find the `difference of tag-min`
- and then filter those that this `difference < rank`
- and find the max of them (max of the tag that are ok)
- increase 1 to find the one missing

*test it before using it to be sure, i tested it 3-4 times seemed ok,
for big collection if you have many different tags, this is better i think. (the above addtoset can cause memory problems)

[Test code here](https://cmql.org/play/?q=70598988-1-m)

```js
aggregate(
[{"$setWindowFields":
  {"output":{"rank":{"$denseRank":{}}, "min":{"$first":"$tag"}},
   "sortBy":{"tag":1}}},
 {"$set":{"difference":{"$subtract":["$tag", "$min"]}}},
 {"$match":{"$expr":{"$lt":["$difference", "$rank"]}}},
 {"$group":{"_id":null, "last":{"$max":"$tag"}}},
 {"$project":{"_id":0, "missing":{"$add":["$last", 1]}}}])
```